# Post csv content to Web Api

Tags: rest

I have a c# console application which post .csv content to a web service. If I run my solution through VS, it runs perfectly fine but after deploying web service on IIS I keep getting Multiple Choice Status Code 300 error. Not sure how to resolve that. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are relatively simple but I cannot think of other possibilities based on your description.

One of my recent designs had a literal in the code that when I deployed it ended up using a different port which I had forgotten to change to a relative reference.

If not that then the other problem I had with it was because I used JSON to link to the web service. While it worked when viewing in VS when deployed my JSON reference was actually incorrect. specifically it had to do with code in my web.config file, which would be the app.config file for your console application. I had used the code

standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"

when I should have also added

defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"

to make the code work